# Is there any reason why free sugar consumption should be limited to low amounts?

Tags: health-education, physical-health, who-world-health-org, healthcare-data

The terminology *free sugars* is possibly related to mono and dissacharides. It is not clear to me if it means precisely just refined sugars or both, refined and not refined.

[There is a WHO study](http://www.who.int/en/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/healthy-diet) recommending *eat free sugars in low amounts*. Here is a [related post](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/16358/11906) with an in some-respects illuminating answer.

For example, glucose is an energy source for the metabolism. Limiting that  sounds counterintuitive. It has been suggested that it is cariogenic, but it doesn't seem enough of a reason for limitation, as we could ingest it without much contact to the teeth, so that is would be dissolved only in the stomach.

So, what are the unhealthy facts related to free sugars that imply reducing the intake?

Comment: Could you clarify your third paragraph ("As glucose…")? – E.g. Did you mean "in a 'box'", transpiring that the sugars would not come into contact with the teeth?

Comment: @LangLangC thanks. Yes, it's just an idea in same direction that 'it seems not enough not to eat glucose just for being cariogenic

Comment: "Sugar, Uric Acid, and the etiology of diabetes and obesity" https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3781481/  This may help contribute to an answer to your question.

Comment: Sure. Thanks @Gordon

Comment: Note:  sucrose contains fructose.

Comment: Richard J. Johnson, one of the authors in above study, also wrote a book called "The Sugar Fix".  I should underline again that common table sugar (sucrose) is in the same category as fructose and HFCS. Do I personally still eat sugar?  Yes, but I have cut down considerably on my intake.

Comment: Yes I'm trying the same, but not reducing carbohydrates intake, they are pretty good specially in the morning (at least to my body)

Comment: @santimirandarp Yes, I am the same way.